# display div athough only another id triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got some problems adressing only one div.

When I click on "impressum" only the impressum is shown inside the `<div class="ContentBox">`. But when I click on "AboutMe" it's showing both div's (aboutMe and impressum)

Am I blind??

Thats what i got:

```
        <div id="menu">
        <div class="inhalt">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="img/menu/home.png">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="ContentBox_open" id="AboutMe"><img src="img/menu/ich.png">Über mich</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="ContentBox_open" id="impressum"><img src="img/menu/impressum.png">Impressum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ContentBox">
        <div class="close"><img id="ContentBox_close" src="img/menu/kategorien.png" alt="close"></div>
        <div id="impressumTxt" style="display:none;">
            <h1>Impressum</h1>
            <p>bla blub bla bla </p>
        </div>
        <div id="AboutMeTxt" style="display:none;">
            <h1>Über mich</h1>
            <p>bla blub bla bla </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function(){
            // impressum anzeigen
            $('.ContentBox_open').click(
                function(event) {
                    var ContentId = event.target.id;
                    $('#'+ContentId+'Txt').fadeTo( 10, 0.90 );
                    $('.ContentBox').fadeTo( "slow", 0.90 );
                }
            );

            // impressum ausblenden
            $('#ContentBox_close').click(
                function() {
                    $('.ContentBox').fadeTo( 1000, 0 );
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a class to your Textsection of About Me and Impressum to hide them before you show antoher section.

In your case, a opened section is not closes before a another is openend.

Just add `$('.class').hide()` before you open the new section

[Fiddel as an example](http://jsfiddle.net/948mcqdk/)

Comment: This approach flickers *if you re-select the current item*. You will note I used `$('.content').not($target).hide();` in my own example to avoid hiding the item selected: http://jsfiddle.net/zo83qpdq/1/

Comment: yeah you're right. Didn't thought about that. thanks.

Comment: Cool guys!! The combination of your two postst are perfecet!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide all child content divs when you close the container. Otherwise they are still visible when you fadein the parent container again. Always make sure items with a common behavior have a common class you can access (I added `class="content"` for this example):

e.g.

```
$('.ContentBox').fadeTo(1000, 0, function(){
    $(this).find('.content').hide()
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zo83qpdq/

```
    $(function () {
        // impressum anzeigen
        $('.ContentBox_open').click(function (event) {
            var ContentId = event.target.id;
            $('#' + ContentId + 'Txt').fadeTo(10, 0.90);
            $('.ContentBox').fadeTo("slow", 0.90);
        });

        // impressum ausblenden
        $('#ContentBox_close').click(function () {
            $('.ContentBox').fadeTo(1000, 0, function(){
                $(this).find('.content').hide()
            });
        });
    });
```

If you want only one div to show at a time you need to change the show logic to hide all other content divs.

e.g. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zo83qpdq/1/